# Facebook Graph API - publish Flash Attachment

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling with the new graph api, trying to publis stream with flash attachment. However docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api says its only possible to post /PROFILE_ID/feed with arguments: message, picture, link, name, description , I have discovered that even other works (caption, ...) Now I would like to guess correct arguments for publishing flash attachment but no luck: type (flash), swfsrc, imgsrc, width, height, expanded_width, expanded_height all those does not seems to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share a list of additional arguments you discovered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey - publishing Flash doesn't work with the new Graph API. Vote for this bug to help speed up the process of getting it working

http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10672

Comment: thnx, that was my bugreport :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you still being capable of publishing flash in facebook using the stream.publish method (**https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish? access_token=....**) and using the publish stream rules of the old API, the only thing that took me a lot of time working around, was that the JSON attachment parameter **MUST** use double quotes, not the single ones that are on the documentation
**"**  <---- these, **not these** ------>  **'**